# eclipse debug does not step into new activity

Tags: android, eclipse

When running Eclipse debug, the debugger does not step into GameActivity class. I am calling this code in a view class to open another activity.

```
    Intent gameIntent= new Intent(myContext,GameActivity.class);

---->   myContext.startActivity(gameIntent);

   --->         //next line of code
```

I have checked the debug version to match the API version. 
I have tried using F5,F6 and neither of them will step into the actual GameActivity activity class. I have put breakpoints in GameActivity activity class. It simply will not break in the GameActivity class.

Thanks for any help

Please help.

Comment: I would not expect that to work - there is no direct flow of program logic from the old Activity to the new, as even if they are in the same process, the path of causation involves asynchronous interprocess communication with the Activity manager that runs in a distinct system process into which the debugger normally has no visibility (and on a secured device, cannot have any).

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a breakpoint at the `onCreate` method of your `GameActivity` class. Step-into (at least in Eclipse) doesn't actually understand the transition betwen intents.